# How to disable "do not use ids in selectors" in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

In sublime text 3 with the sublimelinter plugin (linter / css) how to disable these warnings IDs and padding specifically
[warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vv6v.jpg)

Comment: What linter are you using?

Comment: CssLint (warnings in css id selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### .csslintrc

CSSLint allows you to disable [its rules](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Rules) using the `.csslintrc` in your project root.

**Example:**

```
{
    "ids": false
}
```

### .sublimelinterrc

The same thing can be achieved using Sublime Linter's own [configuration file](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/settings.html#sublimelinterrc-settings), which is basically making use of CSSLint's `--ignore` [command-line parameter](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Command-line-interface#options).

**Example:**

```
{
    "linters": {
        "csslint": {
          "ignore": ["ids]
        }
      }
}
```